# How to utilize Dogmeat's fetch?

Tags: fallout-4

How does Dogmeat's fetch work (at least from the player's point of view)?

I ask because like 95% of the time I command him to fetch something (item, containers, enemies too), he doesn't find anything. Is it a radius thing and it's just really short?

I even asked him to find enemies, *near* enemies (like 50m), who were in plain sight, and got nothing from him.

How do I actually use it?

Please note that I'm **not** asking why it's there or what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The first time I used it was in the northernmost scrapyard (where they dumped the Sentry bot) and he found me a Fatman.

Therefore, I suppose the intended use is finding all the hidden things in the world that you would miss on the first glance (and probably on the second and third as well).

Comment: Yeah that would work for fetch in general, but usually his fetch doesn't find anything in the first place. That's my problem. Thank you though.

Comment: That would suggest that there was nothing to find in that particular spot. I don't think he reacts to junk items, just "valuable" things.

Answer (score 1):

Dogmeat's fetch will collect items of value, such as weapons, and stim packs. It appeard to work within medium proximity, and it does not work in quick succession.

Furthermore, dogmeat will also fetch items out of display cases. This is an exploit that can be useful in situations where you would not be able to immediately access the display case.

> As a good example, you can use dogmeat to 'fetch' the cryolator out of the master display box, in the overseers office, in vault 111.

There is also a bug where you can 'pick up' an item just as dogmeat lowers his head to 'fetch' it. Both you and dogmeat will each pick up the item, duplicating it.

> This particular exploit is especially useful if you use it to duplicate the 'Your S.P.E.C.I.A.L.' book from Shaun's room, which in turn can be used in multiples to boost your S.P.E.C.I.A.L. to perfect 10s. Note that Dogmeat will not fetch the book if it has already been used to allocate a S.P.E.C.I.A.L. point.

Comment: So does it only work on valuable items?

Comment: I think it goes off usage. Dogmeat mostly finds stimpacks and chems, for me. He will find unique gear, but not run of thw mill gear. He will also pick up the "Your S.P.E.C.I.A.L." book, but only when it has not been used.

Comment: Would like confirmation that dogmeat can pick up regular magazines or bobbleheads.